# Can not cast class to generics in java

Tags: java, generics

Please help resolve an issue regarding generics. I tried many ways but it's still not working.
Problem is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Utils.execute(new TestAction(), new TestCallBack());
}
```

Compiler show error:

```
The method execute(Action<?>, CallBack<?,Action<?>>) in the type Utils is not applicable for the arguments (ImplementClass.TestAction, ImplementClass.TestCallBack)
```

My classes is:
Action class:

```
public abstract class Action<R> {
public R getResult() {
    return null;
}
}
```

TestAction class is:

```
class TestAction extends Action<String> {
    @Override
    public String getResult() {
        return super.getResult();
    }
}
```

Callback class is:

```
public interface CallBack<R, A extends Action<R>> {
public void onCall(A action);}
```

TestCallback class is:

```
class TestCallBack implements CallBack<String, TestAction> {

    @Override
    public void onCall(TestAction action) {

    }

}
```

And Utils class is:

```
public class Utils {
public static void execute(Action<?> action, CallBack<?, Action<?>> callback) {

}
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any reason why `execute` 'uses' type parameters, but then again does not use them? Since you refer to them as `<?>`?

Comment: I made a sample to demo my issue in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the `execute` method is `CallBack<?, Action<?>>`, and `Action` there means the `Action` class itself, subclass of it is not allowed. What you need there is - `? extends Action<?>`, which means either `Action` or some subclass of it.

Try changing the method signature -

```
public static void execute(Action<?> action, CallBack<?, ? extends Action<?>> callback) {
```

---

Note:

Generics are not co-variant. Take for example a method as follows -

```
static void method(List<Object> l) {}
```

And an invocation as follows is not allowed -

```
method(new ArrayList<String>());
```

Comment: What is the reason for the difference?

Comment: @BheshGurung: That was a hint to put the explanation in your answer ;)

Comment: It doesn't work. I just copy parse it into Utils class. But now IDE show error: No enclosing instance of type ImplementClass is accessible. Must qualify the allocation with an enclosing instance of type ImplementClass 
 (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of ImplementClass).

Comment: @LeoNguyen That's an unrelated error - make `A` a `static` nested class.

Comment: yes. Proplem is my class is not static. But how the way to work with non static class?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change two things,

**TestCallBack** should be like this -

```
public static class TestCallBack implements CallBack<String, Action<String>> {
  @Override
  public void onCall(Action<String> action) {
  }
}
```

and, **Utils** should be like this -

```
public static class Utils {
  // You need to ensure the same type, not just try and accept anything.
  public static <T> void execute(Action<T> action, CallBack<?, Action<T>> callback) {
  }
}
```

or using inner classes of a class called `Question` -

```
public abstract class Action<R> {
  public R getResult() {
    return null;
  }
}

public class TestAction extends Action<String> {
  @Override
  public String getResult() {
    return super.getResult();
  }
}

public interface CallBack<R, A extends Action<R>> {
  public void onCall(A action);
}

public class TestCallBack implements CallBack<String, TestAction> {
  @Override
  public void onCall(TestAction action) {
  }
}

public class Utils {
  public void execute(Action<?> action, CallBack<?, ? extends Action<?>> callback) {
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  Question question = new Question();
  question.new Utils().execute(question.new TestAction(), question.new TestCallBack());
}
```

Comment: Why does `TestCallBack` need to change?

Comment: It work. But TestCallBack & TestAction must be static class. How the way to implement them as inner class?

Comment: @PaulBellora To ensure that the Action and Callback are actually compatible.

Comment: @LeoNguyen I did this as static inner classes. You want them as normal inner classes?

Comment: @LeoNguyen That's a different problem that you should try to solve separately from this post.